# What does the Android LogCat tag MFV_COMMON mean?

Tags: android, logcat

I am debugging an app that has thrown what looks like an error with the tag: MFV_COMMON.

I am not an Android developer, but I'm trying to get a basic idea of what is going wrong.

What does this tag mean?

The full error message in LogCat is as follows:

```
E/MFV_COMMON(179): [eValDeInit] close VCodec_ValFd, VCodec_ValFd = -1
```

Please note I am not an Android developer so a basic, top-level explanation would be much appreciated if possible.

Comment: VCodec_ValFd has something to do with playing audio oder video files....

Comment: Sorry, audo **oder** video files? Do you mean audio **over** video files? Just checking incase oder is some kind of acronym

Comment: ha....no sorry, I´m a german and just wrote oder insetad of or...:)

Comment: I think some mediaplayer here is doing anything. I also seen by debugging my phone some error log from my media player although no video or audio file was running....